# Programmatically set android:windowIsTranslucent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles, android-windowmanager

I was able to create a floating activity after following this tutorial http://cases.azoft.com/android-tutorial-floating-activity/

However, to do so, I had to add this line in `styles.xml` :

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

Is it possible to have the same effect using only Android/Java code ? (e.g. in `Activity.onAttachedToWindow()` or so...)

Thanks in advance for your help.

**[EDIT 01]** `styles.xml` must not be changed (and I'm not supposed to know what's in it...). But for testing purposes, I'm using the default one:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>
</resources>
```

**[EDIT 02]**  [Resources.Theme.applyStyle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html)  seems to do what I want (according to the API description: *"Place new attribute values into the theme"* ).
So I created the following `custom_style.xml` :

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyCustomStyle" >
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then, in `onAttachedToWindow()` , I called:

```
getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.MyCustomStyle, true);
```

But it didn't have any effect...

Comment: could you find a solution for that? I have something like 20 themes for my app and I don't want to copy them all just for adding this property...

Comment: Sorry but I didn't find the solution I was hoping for. Instead, I hacked my way around this limitation using the [Xposed framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)... I don't suggest you do that for your app.

Comment: Thanks. My solution is to extend my complete activity (no extra functions in there) and define both in the manifest. One with a translucent theme on without. And then I decide on runtime which one to start, override the theme of the activity (translucent will always stay as it was defined in the theme that is used in the manifest) and that's it... actually, copying themes does not work either, as it really seems to use the trnslucent property from the theme used in the manifest, always...

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to have the same effect using only Android/Java code ?

I am afraid, No. You will have to do it in `styles.xml` only. AFAIK value of `android:windowIsTranslucent` alone can't be changed programatically.

When we call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` the Activity class provides empty graphical window on which we set our content ie.views. And a theme is applied to this window and then the content are loaded on this view.

Hence the sequence will be,

1. call to `super.onCreate()`
2. setting theme for the activty.
3. seting the content views for that activity.

eg.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

<!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<!-- Application theme.without title bar -->
<style name="AppTheme.NoTitleBar" parent="AppBaseTheme">

<!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<!--Floating activity theme -->
<style name="Theme_Translucent" parent="android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Then set your theme for `Floating activity` as follows:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Translucent); // Set here
    setContentView(...)
}
```

Comment: Why not ? Also, if it is really not possible programmatically, could I at least create another theme (in another xml file) that has the `android:windowIsTranslucent` item then use it to "wrap" the original style (I must not alter the original `style.xml`).

Comment: yes you can achieve it by creating another theme having android:windowIsTranslucent item.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but that would _replace_ the original `styles.xml`. Can't I just _append_ my custom style ? I've found [getTheme().applyStyle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html) which (according to the API description _"Place new attribute values into the theme"_) seems to do what I want. However, when I created a `custom_style.xml` (which contains `<resources><style name="MyCustomStyle"><item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item></style></resources>`) It didn't work.

Comment: In order to _append_ `custom_style.xml`, I used `getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.MyCustomStyle, true)` in `onAttachedToWindow()`

Comment: plz post your style.xml

Comment: I just added it in the initial post.

Answer (score 3):

do this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
     w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, 
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
     w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, 
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There [a new method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setTranslucent(boolean)) appeared in Android R

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as per the api doc: Convert an activity, which particularly with R.attr.windowIsTranslucent or R.attr.windowIsFloating attribute, to a fullscreen opaque activity, or convert it from opaque back to translucent.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say about to do this programatically .. but if you need to do this you can give a try like this ..

Add theme to you activity in manifest file like this ..

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Example :-

```
  <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidhackerphonelocker.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Hope it solves some problem of your's ..

Comment: This does not include anything about translucent or floating. This is an opaque fullscreen theme with no title bar. The question was asking for help making a floating window translucent through code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    processSetTheme(this);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.realTranslucent);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=19){
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


<color name="realTranslucent">#00000000</color>
```

Comment: You might add at least a bit of explanation of how your code answers the question

Answer (score 0):

if android.app.Dialog

```
window.setDimAmount(0f)
window.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since API level 30 there is now a [`setTranslucent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setTranslucent(boolean)) method:

> Convert an activity, which particularly with `R.attr.windowIsTranslucent` or `R.attr.windowIsFloating` attribute, to a fullscreen opaque activity, or convert it from opaque back to translucent.

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setTranslucent(boolean))