# How to set false for windowIsTranslucent in android programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml

I have the following item in the app theme

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

But I want to set it to false after launching the program in the first Activity. I want to apply it to all activities.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951852/programmatically-set-androidwindowistranslucent

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is to create a second theme and apply it to the activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_second);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```